# Tempdb approaching disk max: Is it OK to wait?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tempdb

Today my `tempdb` pushed up to the edge of the disk allocated. Currently, said disk only has 10 MB left. I'm pretty sure some bad reports run by a colleague earlier in the day pushed up the `tempdb` to this size.

However, now I've got a `tempdb` size of 20932 MB and a space available of 20373 MB. So it seems like we've got plenty of space in there to work with. I'd rather wait until the weekend to do a restart and bring it back to a more reasonable size. Am I OK to let this ride, as long as something unusual doesn't happen again?

Working with SQL Server 2012 here. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a big deal -- in fact, it's the way a lot of people handle tempdb in the first place:

- Add [multiple data files](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/trace-flags-1117-1118-tempdb-configuration/)
- Pre-size files equally to nearly fill tempdb drive
- Set autogrowth to a small increment

If the space you have in there is empty and caused by a rogue report, I wouldn't worry about it, period.

(This does assume you've set up tempdb on a drive by itself, as is generally recommended. If you have other things on the drive that may require the space, you have to decide if there's a risk, and how to handle it).